# Compatibility of flow and inverse flow of a non-autonomous ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we are given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\times [0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^d$, s.t. the ODE
\begin{align}
\dot{y}(t)&= f(y(t),t), \quad t\in[0,T]\newline
      y(0)&= x
\end{align}
is well-posed, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ (e.g. $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ with bounded derivative). Then we can define the flow of this ODE to be the map $[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d\ni(t,x)\mapsto \phi_t(x)\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Moreover we can define the ODE reversed in time:
\begin{align}
\dot{z}(s)&= -f(z(s),T-s), \quad s\in[0,T]\newline
      z(0)&= \xi
\end{align}
for any $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and a corresponding reverse flow $[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d\ni(s,x)\mapsto \psi_s(\xi)\in\mathbb{R}^d$. I can manage to prove the identity
\begin{equation}
\psi_s(\phi_t(x)) = \phi_{t-s}(x)
\end{equation}
for any $0\leq s\leq t \leq T$.

Under what circumstances does $\phi_t(\psi_s(x)) = \phi_{t-s}(x)$ also hold? I am having trouble proving this (I tried showing, that both sides satisfy the same ODE, so I can conclude with uniqueness, but there I run into well-definedness issues). What I can prove however is
\begin{equation}
\phi_t(\psi_s(x)) = \psi_{s-t}(x)
\end{equation}
for any $0\leq t\leq s \leq T$.

Heuristically speaking it shouldn't matter, if I move backwards first and then forwards or vice versa. I read other posts on this website about it, and it seems to have something to do with whether the initial ODE is autonomous or not, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhat incomplete for non-autonomous ODE to leave the initial time out of the flow. If you include it, writing $$x(t)=\Phi(t;t_0,x_0)$$ where $x(t_0)=x_0$, then
$$
\phi_t(x)=\Phi(t;0,x)~~\text{and}~~\psi_s(x)=\Phi(T-s;T,x)
$$
The first claim then resolves to
$$
\psi_s(\phi_t(x))=\Phi(T-s;T,\Phi(t;0,x)).
$$
This does not fit together. Neither does the reverse direction
$$
\phi_t(\psi_s(x))=\Phi(t;0,\Phi(T-s;T,x))
$$

---

What is correct is to split the moves $0\to t\to t-s$ and $0\to-s\to t-s$ as
$$
\phi_{t-s}(x)=\Phi(t-s;t,\Phi(t;0,x))=\Phi(t-s;t,\phi_t(x)),\\
\phi_{t-s}(x)=\Phi(t-s;-s,\Phi(-s;0,x)),
$$
but there is no way to introduce $\psi$ as defined (except if $t=T$, but this is not the general case of the claim).

Comment: I think I understand your reasoning. But how can $\Phi(-s;0,x)$ be well-defined? The ODE only lives on the interval $[0,T]$.

Comment: It just does not fit together, $\phi_t$ is a move from time $0$ to time $t$, $\psi_s$ is a move from time $T$ to time $T-s$, there need to be connection pieces that are neither of these functions. For autonomous systems that would be trivially true, there would be no restrictions on the domain that depend on the initial time, and $\psi_s=\phi_{-s}$.

Comment: Perhaps one could try to repair the follow-up claims that this alleged composition rule is used for?

Comment: To be specific I am concerned with the proof of Theorem 1 from this paper : https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.12998. The goal there is to show that the map $\phi_T(\cdot)$ can not be equal to a certain function $h$. The proof uses some version of a flow property, which at I thought was clear, but now it seems to me that this flow property is not really well-defined there, and the proof doesn't work. But maybe I am just not seeing something.

Comment: The theorem is concerned with flows of autonomous ODE. There you have the (semi-) group property, and going backwards below zero is carefully justified by showing that the orbit in question is closed and can thus be periodically continued.

Comment: Did you understand what the desired homeomorphism in the classification task is? A sufficient set of graded features from which one can easily read of the class and that allows perfect reconstruction?

Comment: I see now, that the paper is about autonomous ODE; I am surprised how I was able to not read that. The extension via "looping" is also fine (I guess one has to justify here, that the semi-group property of the flow also can be extended in a meaningful way).

But your second comment confuses me. If perfect reconstruction is the goal, why wouldn't we just pick some function $h$ that is not a homeomorphism. Since $\phi_T$ has to be one, one would've already found an easy target function, that can't be modelled.

Comment: I meant that second comment not as a leading question, but honest curiosity. A homeomorphism preserves all information. Classification, as I understand it, usually reduces information, losing unimportant detail information, noise. A homeomorphism means that the original image can be perfectly reconstructed from the (localized?) classification. // But it was not explicitly said what the target states of the homeomorphism should be, how they should be structured, so I might miss some unstated, implicit convention.

Comment: To me their thought process (which was motivated by this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.01681) goes as follows (I will use a bit of Machine LEarning terminology):

1. Suppose we have some "weight" function $\Theta$ defined on $[0,T]$, which defines an ODE $\dot{y}(t) = f_{\Theta}(y(t),t)$ ($f$ can be seen as the "activation" function)

2. If $f$ and $\Theta$ are "nice" enough, we can define a corresponding ODE flow evaluated at time $T$, namely $\phi_T$

3. Fix $f$. Given a vector field $h$, can we find $\Theta$, s.t. $\phi_T = h$?

4. Thm.1 says: No.

Comment: However there seems to be a step 1.5, namely something like "we can switch to the autonomous version of the ODE". But the fact that $\phi_T$ can not represent a certain function is not invariant under projections. So you can not conclude that for a non-autonomous system. So when talking about the representational power of $\phi_T$ for a non-autonomous system we are as smart as before. To address your point more specifically: Where do you see any sort of classification happening? To me this looks more like regression, by using ODE flows.

Comment: $h$ is the homeomorphism, the question is if there is a vector field whose flow provides a homotopy. Thm. 1 says that there are examples where that is not possible *inside the same manifold*. But the loop space exists, and the embedding theorem says that this loop space can be embedded in Euclidean space of double the dimension. Later they show that double the original dimension is sufficient, finding homotopies from $(x,0_d)$ to $(0_d,h(x))$. As far as I read it, $Θ$ does not depend on $t$, it is the same vector field from start to end.

Comment: I have the impression, but not proof, that the counter-examples use a topological impossibility. Like that no flow can reverse the orientation. I'm not sure if there are examples of the construction of counter-examples that do not reduce to a reflection.

Comment: I certainly have to brush up on my knowledge on homotopies, before being able to contribute further. But, reading the introduction, I am fairly convinced, that $\Theta = (\theta_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$, making it $t$-dependent. I also have the impression that these counterexamples can only be reflections. this however would be some sort of classification theorem on non-representable homeomorphisms, which I don't have a clue right now how to tackle that.